# How do I execute numpy.sum() on arbitrary number of indices or lists in a Tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tuples

```
B = [[1, -2, -3], [2, 5, -7], [1, 6, 5], [1, 0,-1], [-5, 2, 9]]
B[0] = np.sum(B,1)
print(B[0])
>>> [-1, 13, 6]
```

However, I want to perform sum over 3 indices, i.e., to express B[0] as sum() of B[1], B[2], B[3]. For generality. Therefore, I humbly request if anyone could kindly tell me, with what sort of command or module I could execute such sum() over arbitrary number of lists in a tuple?

Comment: I'm confused.  Given your example, what result do you want?  Do you want one single number?

Comment: And, by the way, your example code does NOT produce the result you indicate.  `np.sum(B,1)` produces a length 5 array:  `[-4, 0, 12, 0, 6]`.  You need to revisit this.

Comment: Does `B[1:4]` give the values you want to sum?

Comment: @hpaulj ,yes. It is working as expected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Tim Robert , sir, I really apologies but I was looking for an array (or, list) as the outcome of the operation of element wise addition of desired incubated lists in the tuple B. Such that outcome remains a list of same length as of each individual lists in B. Thanks a lot for kind response.

Answer (score 0):

OK, assuming your example up there is showing us what you WANT to receive (because that's NOT what that code produces), what you want is:

```
B[0] = np.sum(B[1:],0)
```

Comment: Syntax error here. `[B[1:],0)`